# I'm writing a program that continuously accepts a number and stops only if the last input number is twice the previous number

Tags: c#

If I input:

1 then 3 then 6, the program still runs but if I did 1 then 3 then 6 then 12 it will terminate.

Here's my code:

```
using System;

namespace ProgExer19
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int n1, n2;
            //Console.Write("ENTER NUMBER: ");
            //int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            do
            {
                Console.Write("ENTER NUMBER: ");
                n1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.Write("ENTER NUMBER: ");
                n2 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            }while (n2 != (n1 * 2) || n1 == (n2 * 2));
            Console.WriteLine("Program will now terminate.");
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Adjust your loop so that you only accept one number in the loop, and then compare it to the previous from the second iteration.

Comment: Do not vandalize your posts. By posting on this site, you've irrevocably granted the Stack Exchange network the right to distribute that content under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/) for as long as it sees fit to do so. For alternatives to deletion, see: [I've thought better of my question; can I delete it?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to read only single number per cycle.

```
    using System;
    
    namespace ProgExer19 {
      class Program {
        public static void Main(string[] args) {
          int n1 = 0, n2 = 0;
          int i = 0;
    
          do {
            n1 = n2;
            Console.Write("ENTER NUMBER: ");
            n2 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            i++;
          } while (n2 != (n1 * 2) || i <= 1);
          Console.WriteLine("Program will now terminate.");
          System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works perfectly fine as what I intended to do and I'm very sorry for the poor question have a great day/night!

Comment: If the first input number is `0` this will (incorrectly?) terminate. Also this terminates if you input `6` and then `3`, that also doesn't seem in line with the question title (as `3` is not twice the previous number (`6`))

Comment: @Knoop I have changed answer according to your remarks